# How to access a subfolder within a asp.net (C#) Project, WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, file-io, io

I have a seemingly basic question, but I can't access a folder inside my project (actually, it is a **project** that is one of the **references of the main project**), which is a folder called "pdfs" that contains 1 PDF that I want to convert to base64.

I put the "pdfs" folder in the same level of the file from where I call it, as I thought it would be easier to access (actionDB.cs file, which is in services/actions/actionDB.cs). The "pdfs" folder is in services/actions/pdfs).

But there is no way to get the correct path of this folder.

On the contrary, if I put the folder in c: , getting `path = "c:\\pdfs"`, and the pdf file there, I can easily find it and convert the pdf perfectly in the code.

Any idea how to access these folders that are inside the projects, as if they were assets? I already put 'copy always: to the destination' and 'type of compilation: content' in the pdf properties, but I still can't access it.

I have already tried the following options:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"pdfs");
```

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"services\actions\pdfs");
```

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.CurrentDirectory), @"services\actions\pdfs");
```

The namespace of the actionsDB is ProjectName.Data.services.actions.

I got results such as IIS/.., or other paths inside VS installation…, Assembly and some weird hashes.

Nothing works...

Could you help me with this?

Thank you very much,

CBD

Comment: asp is meant to run in hosting environments and you should avoid file reads and writes like that. take a look at: [file-providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0) or for example, for configurable filesystem locations you could consider using absolute paths

Answer (score 0):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is probably the most useful for accessing files whose location is relative to the application install directory.

Comment: And if I am still coding the application and it is not "installed" yet?
I mean, if the root now is IIS Express?